# QuickBlox - how to signup and them login new user

Tags: android, quickblox

I was trying to implement the following functionality in QuickBlox  :

1. check if user is not exists
2. if not - sing up
3. sing in ( old user or newly created )

but i was unable to do it . because both singin and singup are async , and also got "token required" error .

Any help would be appreciated.

here is the full code :

```
    ChatService.initIfNeed(this);

    ChatService.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Go to Dialogs screen
            //
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DialogsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List errors) {

            // AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
            //dialog.setMessage("chat login errors: " + errors).create().show();


            QBUsers.signUp(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {


                    QBUsers.signIn(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle params) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                  //TOKEN IS REQUIRED EXCEPTION !  
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: which platform? iOS? Android? JS? REST?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint  - the same question in Javascript

[Sign UP oAuth Tokens Quickblox and oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713402/sign-up-oauth-tokens-quickblox-and-oauth/31722496#31722496)

so you can follow the same way

do the queries one by one inside **onSuccess** callback

Comment: that's exactly what I did , but I am getting TOKEN IS REQUIRED exception in the last  onError statement . please see attached code . I have added full code to original question .